# Custom REGEXP Function to be used in a SQLITE SELECT Statement

Tags: php, regex, model-view-controller, sqlite, routes

I have an SQLITE Database's File which in one of the table columns there is some simple Regular Expressions.

These Expressions are something like **/foo(.*?)*** or **/foo/bar/(.?)** and so on...

Well, when we try to match some text against a Regular Pattern, in PHP, we do:

> preg_match( $pattern, $target, $matches )

Replacing the variables with the content, obviously.

What I would like to do is send ANY STRING as value of a WHERE Clause and, when searching the SQLITE Database's File, use each of the stored Regular Expressions to match a pattern in the given string.

I think that using PHP's sqlite_create_function() I can create some kind of routine to do this, but I don't know exactly how, since is the first time I develop using SQLITE.

If interest, it's part of an MVC Routing of a Framework I'm developing.

Thank you very much, in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SQLiteDatabase::createFunction` documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-create-function.php) or `PDO::sqliteCreateFunction` documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.sqlitecreatefunction.php)

I did something like this:

```
<?php
function _sqliteRegexp($string, $pattern) {
    if(preg_match('/^'.$pattern.'$/i', $string)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
$PDO->sqliteCreateFunction('regexp', '_sqliteRegexp', 2);
?>
```

Use:

```
SELECT route FROM routes WHERE pattern REGEXP 'your/url/string' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: For multi-byte strings, you can use:

`$db->sqliteCreateFunction('regexp', function($pattern, $value) {
    mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
    return (false !== mb_ereg($pattern, $value)) ? 1 : 0;
});`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
e.g. SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `my_column` REGEXP "\/foo(.?)"
```

Comment: It would be if I was trying to pass the Regular Expression.

I would like to work in the other way, sending the full URL request
and one of the Regular Expressions in SQL Database match with it.

Almost like a reverse of preg_match()'s params.

If possible I can avoid some unnecessary loops.