# Correct PreparedStatement for SQL MATCH with unknown value

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

```
String sqlStm = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE TableName MATCH '?'";
               pst.setString(1, keyword.getText());
```

I am doing a full-text search on my database. When I use the above it doesnt execute the sql statement. However, if I were to change the program and give a value to match like this...

```
  String sqlStm = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE TableName MATCH 'technology'";
```

The programme execute. But i want the search to be based on entered text in `keyword` JTextfield. is the formatting correct in the first line. does `MATCH` support `pst.setString()`. What should be the correct statement.

Answer (score 2):

*remove the single quote around the parameter*, it will convert the parameter into a value. Parameter placeolder `?` shouldn't be enclosed with single quotes.

```
String sqlStm = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE TableName MATCH ?";
pst.setString(1, keyword.getText());
```

Comment: this fails, i am using Sqlite

Comment: nope, not event that or `%?%, or MATCH = ?, or TableName = ? ...sucks.

Comment: Can you escape it? like \?

Comment: @SalehOmar escape characters are illegal bro

Comment: I think you should escape twice \\? but I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE TableName  LIKE '%^technology$%'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE TableName REGEXP '^\\technology$'
```

I couldn't really find any article that says SQlite `Like` or `regexp` behaves differently than MySQL so... you may give that a try. If there is anything that differs please share as well.

Comment: needs to reflect unknown value, rather than fixed 'technology'. problem lies in the useage of ? along with `pst.setString()`

Comment: dealing with unknown query expression ONLY, not defined. you missed the point of the question

Comment: @MuminAli sorry mate, that's a real miss. Perhaps try out a [function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663368/custom-regexp-function-to-be-used-in-a-sqlite-select-statement) then..